# Sample function doesn't work on Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I try to compile the following code with Dymola:

```
class abc
  import Modelica.SIunits;
  parameter SIunits.Time delta_t=0.5;

  constant Real a[:]={4,2,6,-1,3,5,7,4,-3,-6};
  Real x;
  Integer j(start=1);
  Integer k=size(a, 1);

algorithm 
  when {(sample(0, delta_t) and j < k),j == 1} then
    x := a[j];
    j := j + 1;
  end when;
end abc;
```

and for `time = 0` the variable `j` starts with `2`. But it should start with `j = 1`.
Does anybody have an idea for this problem?

Comment: You use the vector `{(sample(0, delta_t) and j<k), j==1}` as condition for the when-equation. The two lines of code inside your when-equation become active at the instant when either of the two conditions in your vector becomes true. At `time=0` the condition `j==1` becomes true and the code is executed at that very instant.

Comment: @matth No, the condition j==1 does not _become_ true at time=0, it is true, since "j==1 and pre(j==1) = false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `sample(x,y)` means that sample is true at `x+i*y` where `i` starts at zero.  Which is to say that `sample(0, ...)` becomes true at `time=0`.

Since `j` starts at 1 and `k` is presumably more than 1, it doesn't seem unexpected to me that `sample(0, delta_t) and j<k` should become true at the start of the simulation.

I suspect what you want is:

```
class abc
  import Modelica.SIunits;
  parameter SIunits.Time delta_t=0.5;

  constant Real a[:]={4,2,6,-1,3,5,7,4,-3,-6};
  Real x;
  Integer j(start=1);
  Integer k=size(a, 1);

algorithm 
  when {(sample(delta_t, delta_t) and j < k),j == 1} then
    x := a[pre(j)];
    j := pre(j) + 1;
  end when;
end abc;
```

I don't really see the point of the `j==1` condition.  It is true at the outset which means it doesn't "become" true then.  And since `j` is never decremented, I don't see why it should ever return to the value `1` once it increments for the first time.

Note that I added a `pre` around the right-hand side values for `j`.  If this were in an
`equation` section, I'm pretty sure the `pre` would be required.  Since it is an `algorithm` section, it is mainly to document the intent of the code.  It also makes the code robust to switching from `equation` to `algorithm` section.

Comment: Note, that x will be 0 at time=[0,delta_t). I'm sure if modeler would expect that.

Comment: ok, now j starts with 1 at time 0. But at time t = 0.5 the value of j returns on 1 and starts to increment at t=1. You see the course in the image.
![Value_j](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17773229/Variable_j_falsch.PNG).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is an event at time = 0 triggered by the expression `sample(0, delta_t) and j<k` which becomes true.

But in older versions of Dymola there is an bug with the initialization of discrete variables. For instance even if you remove `sample(0.0, delta_t) and j<k` in dymola74, j will become 2 at time=0. The issue was that the pre values of when clauses, where not initialized correct. As far as I know this is corrected at least in the version FD1 2013.